# How to change video at runtime with vuforia SDK

Tags: android, vuforia

I'm using vuforia SDK on android and I'm working with videoplayback sample code. I want to change the source file of the video at runtime. To do that, when I want to load a new video file, first I change the video file name like this:

```
mMovieName[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/video1.mp4";
```

I checked the path to the video file by loading it from the begining and it's correct.
I put this line in this method:

```
onQCARUpdate(State state)
```

which is run in equal time steps. Then I load the new video like this in the same method:

```
mRenderer.requestLoad(0, mMovieName[0], 0, false);
```

SO in the end it looks like this:

```
@Override
public void onQCARUpdate(State state)
{
    if(loadNewVideo)
    {
        mMovieName[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/video1.mp4";
        mRenderer.requestLoad(0, mMovieName[0], 0, false);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that nothing changes. The initial video continues as it was being played and no errors or crashes. Should I do something aside from these too or is it that I'm completely off?

---

**EDIT:**

I was not actually loading the video. I'm calling load method of videoHelper now but still the video doesn't change. It just freezes and I can hear its sounds.

In VideoPlayback.java I added this method which I'm calling inside onQCarUpdate once a single tap happens:

```
private boolean changeVideo()
{
    boolean result = true;

    mMovieName[STONES] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/video1.mp4";
    mRenderer.requestLoad(STONES, mMovieName[STONES], 0, false);
    mRenderer.loadVideo(STONES);

    return result;
}
```

Also added this method to VideoPlaybackRenderer.java (I just copied these from onSurfaceChanged):

```
public void loadVideo(int i)
{
    if (mVideoPlayerHelper[i] != null)
    {
        if (!mVideoPlayerHelper[i]
            .setupSurfaceTexture(videoPlaybackTextureID[i]))
            mCanRequestType[i] = MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN;
        else
            mCanRequestType[i] = MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN;

        if (mLoadRequested[i])
        {
            mVideoPlayerHelper[i].load(mMovieName[i],
                mCanRequestType[i], mShouldPlayImmediately[i],
                mSeekPosition[i]);
            mLoadRequested[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The address to the video is fine. I tried loading it as the first video and it plays fine. Both videos are on SD storage and I've modified VideoHelper.java to load from SD. I also checked and it does go into loadVideo once I tap outside the target.

**EDIT:**

I had to unload before loading a new video so what worked was this:

```
public void loadVideo(int i)
{
    if (mVideoPlayerHelper[i] != null)
    {
        mVideoPlayerHelper[i].unload();
        if (!mVideoPlayerHelper[i]
            .setupSurfaceTexture(videoPlaybackTextureID[i]))
            mCanRequestType[i] = MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN;
        else
            mCanRequestType[i] = MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN;

        if (mLoadRequested[i])
        {
            mVideoPlayerHelper[i].load(mMovieName[i],
                mCanRequestType[i], mShouldPlayImmediately[i],
                mSeekPosition[i]);
            mLoadRequested[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you explore the code, you can see the requestLoad method does nothing but equalation:

```
public void requestLoad(int target, String movieName, int seekPosition,
        boolean playImmediately)
    {
        mMovieName[target] = movieName;
        mSeekPosition[target] = seekPosition;
        mShouldPlayImmediately[target] = playImmediately;
        mLoadRequested[target] = true;
    }
```

You need to load the video in the Renderer Class:

```
mVideoPlayerHelper[i].load(mMovieName, mCanRequestType, mShouldPlayImmediately, mSeekPosition);
```

Comment: So i did this. What happens is that the last frame that was on the texture freezes and nothing happens after that. If I load the new video before playing the first one I only see a black screen. In both cases I hear the sounds of the first video. I edited my question and added what I'm doing right now.

Comment: Problem solved. thanks. I had to unload before loading a new video

Comment: For anyone who might need it, I added the modified method to the end of my question.

Answer (score 1):

hey unfortunately i dont have 50 reps to comment on any of the previous answers. thanks for sharing your answer soroosh and shayan.

i have tried following the steps you have listed above, but for some reason, it's still not able to load the video from the sd card.

to summarise, i have updated:

1. mMovieName in VideoPlayback.java as below

`mMovieName[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/myVideoName.mp4";`

2. overridden onQCARUpade in VideoPlayback.java with the method listed below

   @Override
   public void onQCARUpdate(State state) {
       if(loadNewVideo)     {
           mMovieName[0] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/myVideoName.mp4";
           mRenderer.requestLoad(0, mMovieName[0], 0, false);
       } }

Where did you get the value for loadNewVideo soroosh? Is this a new variable?

3. added changeVideo method in VideoPlayback.java

   private boolean changeVideo()    {
       boolean result = true;

   ```
   mMovieName[STONES] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/myVideoName.mp4";
   mRenderer.requestLoad(STONES, mMovieName[STONES], 0, false);
   mRenderer.loadVideo(STONES);

   return result;
   ```

   }

4 added loadVideo method to VideoPlaybackRenderer.java:

```
public void loadVideo(int i)
{
    if (mVideoPlayerHelper[i] != null)
    {
        mVideoPlayerHelper[i].unload();
        if (!mVideoPlayerHelper[i]
            .setupSurfaceTexture(videoPlaybackTextureID[i]))
            mCanRequestType[i] = MEDIA_TYPE.FULLSCREEN;
        else
            mCanRequestType[i] = MEDIA_TYPE.ON_TEXTURE_FULLSCREEN;

        if (mLoadRequested[i])
        {
            mVideoPlayerHelper[i].load(mMovieName[i],
                mCanRequestType[i], mShouldPlayImmediately[i],
                mSeekPosition[i]);
            mLoadRequested[i] = false;
        }
    }
}
```

5. lastly, I updated load method in VideoPlayerHelper.java:

   mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/myVideoName.mp4");

Comment: hmm ... this is not an answer, is it?